# Python Pandas Select Index Value Referencing String Value in a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is date sequenced and has 'x' values in one column when there is new information on a particular date.

I want to get the index value of the row for the date before the most recent new information date so I can reference that data for further operations

So my dataframe looks like this:

```
original_df

index      date        value   newinfo
  0     '2007-12-01'     75      Nan
  1     '2007-12-02'     75      Nan
  2     '2007-12-03'     83       x
  3     '2007-12-04'     83      Nan
  4     '2007-12-05'     83      Nan
  5     '2007-12-06'     47       x
  6     '2007-12-07'     47      Nan
  7     '2007-12-08'     47      Nan
  8     '2007-12-09'     47      Nan
```

So I'm interested in referencing row where `original_df.index == 4` for some further operations.

The only way I can think of doing it is very 'clunky'.  Basically I create another dataframe by filtering my original for rows where `newinfo == 'x'`, take the index value of the last row, subtract 1, and use that value to access various columns in that row of the original dataframe using `iloc`.  Code looks like this:

```
interim_df = original_df[original_df['newinfo']=='x']
index_ref_value = interim_df.index[-1] - 1
```

This returns an `index_ref_value` of `4`.

I can then access `value` in `original_df` as follows:

```
original_df.iloc[index_ref_value,1]
```

In other words, I'm access the `value` for `2007-12-05`, the day before the most recent `newinfo`.

This gets the job done but strikes me as complicated and sloppy.  Is there a cleaner, easier, more Pythonic way to find the index_ref_value I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can combine `iloc` and `loc` into one statement:

```
original_df.iloc[original_df.loc[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index-1]
```

the `loc` statement is taking the index of where the condition (where `newinfo` is `x`) and then getting the index of that value. `iloc` then takes those indexes and givies you the result you are looking for

judging from your quesiton, you may need a list of these values in the futre. try `df1.iloc[df1.loc[df1['newinfo'] == 'x'].index-1].index.tolist()`

edit to get the desired output:

```
original_df.iloc[original_df.loc[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index[-1]-1]

# added a [0] at the end below to get just the value of `4`
original_df.iloc[original_df.loc[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index[-1]-1][0]
```

Comment: Breaking it down for myself so I understand the parts better, I just ran the following subset of your answer:  `original_df.loc[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index-1` and `original_df[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index-1` (note the second one didn't have the `loc`).  I'm not exactly clear on what the  `loc` does here.  Could you explain a bit further.  Thx.

Comment: `.loc` in this example returns a dataframe of where the condition is true. `.loc[].*index*` returns the indexes of this new dataframe. These indexes are then used to be passed into `iloc`

Comment: Since I'm looking for the index value in the original dataframe preceding the most recent 'x' date, I think your answer should be edited as follows: `original_df.iloc[original_df.loc[original_df['newinfo'] == 'x'].index[-1]-1]`.  (note the addition of the `[-1]` after index). Did I get that right?

Comment: @Windstorm1981, I'm slightly confused on the *why* but, yes! if that gives you the answer you are looking for, i edited my question to adjust for it

Comment: Yes. My need is for the row just before the most recent update :)